# PHP REGEX preg_replace_callback not matching

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match

[history="e70b3ffc-beaf-423f-b084-72bc5bae3147"]History name here[/history]

and get the ID and the content between the "tags". And although the above works fine at https://regexr.com/3ilt2 it's won't match on my code and I cannot figure out why. Any ideas?

```
    $parsed_string = preg_replace_callback(
        // [history="ID"]ABC[/history]
        '/\[history="(.*?)"\](.*?)\[\/history\]/', 
        function ($matches) {
            return $this->parseHistories( $matches, 'alt-name' );
        }, 
        $parsed_string
    );
```

Comment: Your  code is fine, except for `parseHistories` which I'm assuming is doing something wrong.  Maybe show us that missing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `preg_replace_callback` function works fine in the following code:

```
$parsed_string = "[history=\"e70b3ffc-beaf-423f-b084-72bc5bae3147\"]History name here[/history]";
$parsed_string = preg_replace_callback(
    // [history="ID"]ABC[/history]
    '/\[history="(.*?)"\](.*?)\[\/history\]/', 
    function ($matches) {
        return $matches[1];    // return the first capture group (the UUID)
    }, 
    $parsed_string
);
echo $parsed_string;
```

This outputs the captured UUID `e70b3ffc-beaf-423f-b084-72bc5bae3147`.  There must be a problem with your `parseHistories()` function.

### Demo

Comment: You have added a \ after the [history= which was not there originally and after the UUID the string  I am trying to pass shouldn't have it. are you escaping- I am a bit confused. I can see that the above is working but I cannot understand

Comment: @DimitrisRomeoHavlidis I just cut and paste your pattern, that's all.

Comment: He's talking about subject string. Yes @DimitrisRomeoHavlidis, it's escaping.

Comment: @Revo I'm surprised that his code would even _run_ without escaping a double quote inside a double quoted string.

Comment: I know what you are trying to say, he just doesn't know it.

Comment: It was my mistake, working with migraine today. the original string was coming from a form input so there was no use for the escaping but you were absolutely right - fixed now. - The issue was that the " " received where different ASCII than the quotes I was trying to match

Comment: Also thank you very much for the rextester.com link - awesome and simple tool

Comment: Yeah...it's invaluable for Stack Overflow questions, simply because I can't always have every IDE open at the same time.